# Поменять столбцы в таблице местами MsSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица в MS SQL Server Management Studio. Нужно поменять 2 столбика местами. Как это сделать sql запросом? Менять порядок выбора столбцов в программе нельзя тк заранее неизвестно из какой таблицы будет `SELECT` поэтому запрос всегда `SELECT ALL`. Знаю что можно переименовать столбцы запросом а потом перекинуть значения из одного в другой но это слишком долго.

Comment: Как sql-запросом не знаю, в самой студии (IDE) можно переименовать столбики.

Comment: Столбцы поменять местами нельзя. для этого БД придется физически на диске во всех записях поменять данные местами. т.е. выполнить тот самый update с обменом значениями, который вы говорите будет работать долго. И если встала такая странная задача - значит надо пересмотреть архитектуру приложения. Может сделать, например табличку в которой фиксировать в какой таблице и какие колонки переставлять местами и на основе нее формировать тексты запросов из программы.

Comment: Т.е. я  сам пусть и долго, но  могу это сделать а БД не может?

Comment: в БД не принято реализовывать не нужные возможности. Идеология реляционных БД предполагает, что порядок колонок не имеет значения. поэтому средств обмена их местами никто не делает. тем более что на крайний случай средство есть, вы его уже назвали. Хотя средства разработки структуры БД в таком случае обычно создают новую таблицу с правильной структурой, генерят запрос на перелив данных и потом переименовывают таблицы, но это путь конечно более долгий чем один update и два alter table

Comment: @Mike, в смысле? кто мешает в дизайнере SSMS перетащить столбцы изменив их порядок?

Comment: @teran А дизайнер пишет какими sql запросами он это выполняет ? Все что происходит с БД выполняется в итоге ddl sql. вряд ли есть готовый alter который меняет колонки местами, небось пересоздание таблицы будет выполнять

Comment: @teran посмотрел в гугле. там написано, что для того что бы выполнить эту операцию надо отключить защиту "не выполнять пересоздание таблицы". так что, как я и предполагал дизайнер делает такую операцию пересозданием таблицы

Comment: @Mike не поделитесь ссылкой ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781151/how-to-change-the-column-order-of-an-existing-table-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @Сергей сколько у вас строк то в таблице? что долго менять значения местами?

Comment: @Mike дак может с пересозданием таблицы автора и устроит?

Comment: От 10 до 30 строк в каждой колонке

Comment: @teran Вполне устраивает. Над архитектурой возможно стоит подумать но если не считать этого то это именно то что нужно.

Comment: Если каждую такую задачу решать алтером или пересозданием таблицы, ни к чему хорошему это не приведет, а если каждый раз отключать какую нибудь защиту то sql server в обще может не запуститься в очередной раз)). Вариант со вьюшкой самый простой, в любой момент можно поменять порядок колонок и все.

Comment: @heff таблиц несколько и в приложении мы не знаем из какой конкретно выбираем данные.

Comment: @heff если на каждый чих создавать вьюшку, то тоже ничего хорошего нет. А про "защиту" речь там была про отключение показа предупреждения в SSMS. С данной установленной галкой, у вас в принципе вряд ли получится создать БД с нуля.

Comment: Зачем в обще нужно чтобы столбец был вторым а не третьим, select просто же выдает набор данных не отвечая за его отображение? мы так далеко можем уйти в рассуждениях.

Comment: @heff может нравится, например, когда в таблицах все внешние ключи и часто используемые столбцы находятся в начале, а потом данные. +nullable столбцы в конце таблицы экономят место. Но по сути разницы конечно нет, а подход выборки всего, и ориентации на индексы столбцов - плохая практика, тут никто не спорит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как решение данной задачи предлагаю сделать вьюшку на таблицу с нужным порядком столбцов и к ней уже обращаться в запросе. синтаксис создания представления см здесь https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187956.aspx